# Console.log inside then from fetch not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, expo, fetch-api

I'm trying to debug the code from an expo app (react native) that posts a json to and endpoint. I've added console.log statements inside the then clause after the fetch but they are not printing at all! the other code is running fine :S

```
  sendMessage: (
    token,
    data
  ) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const body = {
        ...data,
      };
      fetch(`${URI_BACKEND}api/create`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE FROM BACKEND", response);
        
        showToastGlobal("success", "top", "Saved", "Message saved successfully");
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => resolve(json))
      .catch(error => {console.log("ERROR FROM THE BACKEND", error); reject(error);});
    });
  },
```

The showToastGlobal function is being executed cause I can see the toast in app, any idea what am I doing wrong? no error log and no response log...

**UPDATE:**
added caller function

```
const sendWholeMessage = (messageId, messageToSend, images, timestamp, userId) => {
    API.sendMessage(token, messageToSend)
    .then(response => {
      if (images[0]) {
        console.log("Sending images...");
        API.saveImages(token, images)
        .then(result => console.log("Response img:", result))
        .catch(error => console.log("ERROR sending images to backend", error));
      }
      console.log("Response Message:", response);
      ...
      deleteLocalCopyOfMessage(messageId);
      console.log("Saving...")
    });
  }
```

The "Response Message" and the "Saving..." console logs both print ok

**UPDATE 2:**
changing

```
        console.log("RESPONSE FROM BACKEND", response);
```

to

```
        console.log("RESPONSE FROM BACKEND", response.status);
```

does print to console, or removing the second argument from console.log (just the string) does also work, so trying to print the response object results in the console.log statement being ignored, any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: if `console.log("RESPONSE FROM BACKEND", response);` isn't running, then you have a rejection

Comment: by the way .... no need to wrap a fetch inside a Promise constructor, since fetch already returns a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX if i have a rejection then showToastGlobal wouldnt't be running, and no error is being printed. Besides the code that calls this code has a console log in the then clause that is printing

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint instead of using console.log?

Comment: @Barmar can't seem to make it work debbuging. I'm working in a remote virtual machine using my cellphone to test.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, not true, did enable debugging but it slows down so much that its unusable

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

does not receive response using fetch API.

### Solution

fetch API need two steps to get the response, so I would suggest you to retrieve response in the second then() clause:

```
  fetch(`${URI_BACKEND}api/create`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json =>         
    console.log("RESPONSE FROM BACKEND", json);        
    showToastGlobal("success", "top", "Saved", "Message saved successfully");)
  .catch(error => {console.log("ERROR FROM THE BACKEND", error); reject(error);});
```

Comment: thats not the case, see updated post, theres a response object but console.log statements were being ignored

Comment: if that case, have u tried to use response.toString()? converting it to string might help